# Python flask API exposing a neural network not working on linux but working on windows

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, flask, keras

I have a python flask API that I worked on for my project, it is exposing a neural network that is given few inputs and returns 1 output.
I was working fine with it on my windows machine, but when I wanted to run it on a linux VM it returns all kind of errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FinBud_Prediction_Service.py", line 47, in <module>
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/pickle_utils.py", line 48, in deserialize_mode                                                                                   l_from_bytecode
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/pickle_utils.py", line 46, in deserialize_mode                                                                                   l_from_bytecode
    model = saving_lib.load_model(filepath, safe_mode=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 277, in load_model
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 265, in load_model
    _load_state(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 453, in _load_state
    _load_container_state(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 510, in _load_container_s                                                                                   tate
    _load_state(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 422, in _load_state
    trackable._load_own_variables(weights_store.get(inner_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 3513, in _load_own_variab                                                                                   les
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Layer 'dense' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['dense                                                                                   /kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0']
```

It's giving me this error and I am not able to make it work despite trying a lot of things like reinstalling everything from scratch.

I tried reinstalling everything from scratch and tried creating a new Linux VM.
I also tried using other versions of the libraries like Keras and Tensorflow.

Comment: where did you build this file `filename`? you need to review how you are saving the model, because when you trained and saved the model in windows, pickle messed something and is now not compatible in Linux. also check that lib version are same between windows and linux.

Comment: I tried building the model in WSL on my machine, still didn't work, then I built the model on the VM itself and then it worked.